# Jenkins does not build the app with gradle

Tags: android, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins to build the app in the CI system. In the config for the build I set that I want to use gradle wrapper. I have set the Wrapper location to:

```
C:\Users\myuser\myproject\android\MyAppFolder
```

In the list of the tasks to be executed I put `build`.

The build "succeeds" but actually it does not build the app.

If I go to the command line and I run

```
.\gradlew build
```

it works.

If instead of running the "build" I run "tasks" from Jenkins this is what I see in the log:

```
14:00:07 [Android] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\myuser\myproject\android\MyAppFolder\gradlew.bat tasks build && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
14:00:12 :tasks
14:00:12 
14:00:12 ------------------------------------------------------------
14:00:12 All tasks runnable from root project
14:00:12 ------------------------------------------------------------
14:00:12 
14:00:12 Build Setup tasks
14:00:12 -----------------
14:00:12 init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
14:00:12 wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]
14:00:12 
14:00:12 Help tasks
14:00:12 ----------
14:00:12 buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'Android'.
14:00:12 components - Displays the components produced by root project 'Android'. [incubating]
14:00:12 dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'Android'.
14:00:12 dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'Android'.
14:00:12 dependentComponents - Displays the dependent components of components in root project 'Android'. [incubating]
14:00:12 help - Displays a help message.
14:00:12 model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'Android'. [incubating]
14:00:12 projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'Android'.
14:00:12 properties - Displays the properties of root project 'Android'.
14:00:12 tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'Android'.
14:00:12 
14:00:12 To see all tasks and more detail, run gradlew tasks --all
14:00:12 
14:00:12 To see more detail about a task, run gradlew help --task <task>
```

So it looks like the tasks for building the app are not there. It looks like I'm actually pointing to some other "root project".

**EDIT**
It looks like the proble is here:

```
cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\myuser\myproject\android\MyAppFolder\gradlew.bat tasks build && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
```

if I do the same from the command line I get the same issue. If I change the directory and then I run `gradlew build`everything works.

It looks like if I run it from a different folder the the gradle.build that is used is not the correct one

Comment: Try `C:\Users\myuser\myproject\android\MyAppFolder\gradlew.bat build`

Comment: @shmakova I tried it that's when I get success but with no build. The log you see is when I changed it to get the list of the tasks too. I edited the question to make it clear

Comment: Do you have task "tasks" in your build.gradle?